# How do I close all MDIChildFrames that are in a MDIParentFrame?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

How do I close all MDIChildFrames that are in a MDIParentFrame? Is there a built in function to do this?

```
frame = MyFrame(None) #MDIParentFrame
frame.Show()

child1 = MDIChildFrame(frame, "MDIChildFrame")
child1.Show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to get the client window through [GetClientWindow()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_m_d_i_parent_frame.html#ad56178287336d30e658c636a8cb096da) method, then get list of child windows for that client window through [GetChildren()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_window.html#ad500085ad0511879b5e018706c91a494), iterate through this list, check whether child window is wxMDIChildFrame using [IsKindOf()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_object.html#af40d580385cf4f8112fae7713404b01e) macro, if it returns true then call [Close()](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_window.html#a3e44f4a494fc9ef4346c4fba70c8de0c).
wxPython classes should have the same list of methods as C++ version.

Comment: Nice, this function wasn't even on the API but it still worked

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be a lot simpler to use wxWindow::GetChildren()

http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_wxwindow.html#wxwindowgetchildren

You will have to be careful though: the MDIChildFrame windows are NOT children of the MDIParentFrame, they are grandchildren via a wxMDIClientWindow

http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.8/wx_wxmdiclientwindow.html